# Spring Boot webflux with reactive mongodb. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.acme.dao.model.Transit.<init>()

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm having trouble hooking up my repository to my local instance of mongo db. I think everything is set up correctly, the shape of the documents in mongo compass looks the same as the POJO. But when I run it I get this error

```
2021-09-05 16:08:37.745 ERROR 19564 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate com.acme.dao.model.Transit using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments ] with root cause
```

From other SO questions I think it might be a driver compatibility issue. I've got version `5.0.2` of mongodb running. Here's my gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.foretold'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:2.5.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.5.4'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.4'
    testImplementation 'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:3.0.0'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test:3.4.9'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Here's the POJO

```java
@Document
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Transit {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String planetName;
    private Double decimal;
    private Long epochSeconds;
    private String key;
    private Double speed;

    public Transit(String planetName) {
        this.planetName = planetName;
    }

    public Transit(String planetName, String key) {
        this.planetName = planetName;
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

This is a sample document as it's living in my collection right now.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"613520c592d3c015a17c7029"},
"planetName":"Pluto",
"decimal":75.27915837864154,
"key":"075-16",
"speed":0.01849046574763826,
"epochSeconds": {"$numberLong":"-2198981873"}}
```

The docs here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#compatibility.matrix don't seem to reference version 5 of mongo at all, so I'm at a loss on what to do. Or if it's possible that there's something else wrong?

Comment: It says *Transit using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments*, But u have already put @NoArgsConstructor. Did you do clean & install?

Comment: in the Json file you wrote **_id** , but in your model is **id** . so change `String id` to `String _id` and try again.

Comment: @varman Tried running clean and build again (I don't have install as a gradle script) and same problem.

Comment: @mr1554 Thanks for the suggestion, I went and tried with `_id` and also tried changing string to `ObjectId` which is the bson type it's using (with both `_id` and `id`) and it still gives the constructor error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was with the lombok annotations. When I removed them and added all my constructors manually it worked. I then ran into a problem with it actually setting data to the objects when it queried, and that was fixed by replacing the @Data annotation with manually added getters and setters.